# Resizing bitmap to fit screensize

Tags: android, bitmap, background-image, android-xml

I have a LinearLayout where I set the background like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_splash"
```

and my drawable is set up like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
       <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bg_splash"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

My problem now is that the image is not being resized to the screensize. I want it to get a bit smaller, because it has the dimension 1280x797

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you have match_parent or wrap_content on LinearLayout?

Comment: Do you want to fill the entire screen without keeping aspect ratio?

Comment: I have both for the height and the width fill_parent. I'd like to keep the aspect ratio

Answer (score -1, accepted):

possible solution might be to use RelativeLayout instead and set an imageView as the first view in Your xml that fills the RelativeLayout. Then put this image into the imageView and declare

```
   android:scaleType="centerInside".
```